# ThreadingLayer[Subtract] produces internal error

Tags: bugs, neural-networks

The documentation states that `Subtract` is a valid function for use in `ThreadingLayer`. This produces an internal error however. Try:

```
net = NetGraph[<|
"Minus" -> ThreadingLayer[Subtract]|>, {{NetPort["in1"], NetPort["in2"]} -> "Minus"}]
```

and evaluate on some input

```
net[<|"in1" -> 1, "in2" -> 2|>]
```

> NetGraph::interr: An internal error occurred. Please contact Wolfram
>   Research.

I already reported this to WRI.

Comment: It might be better if you split off the workaround into an answer instead of putting it in the question.

Comment: @J.M. Done that. Thanks

Comment: @Sascha Do you know how `Clip` should work in `ThreadingLayer`?

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev No idea, together with `ElementwiseLayer` however `Clip` works like one would expect.

Answer (score 4):

A workaround is using `ThreadingLayer[#1-#2&]` instead.

Answer (score 4):

This has been fixed for 11.1.1.